# redirecting two pairs of numbers with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have URLs which I need to strip and redirect the numbers for categories and products.

**Category**
example.com/9-bird-tables

**Product**
example.com/bird-tables/59-slate-roof-bird-table/

**They need to be:**
example.com/bird-tables/
example.com/bird-tables/slate-roof-bird-table/

So, the number appears in a different place depending on what you're viewing. I cant work out the rules and I'm running out of time. Can anyone help?. I've tried the following, but it only works for the first set of numbers, and not the second

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+-(.+?)/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your rule to this with 2 capturing groups:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\d+-(.+)$ $1$2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Hi, following on, this does indeed work. But it also causes problems with numbers in image paths. 

example.com/image/cache/catalog/product/1802-530x530.jpg

. gets turned into.

example.com/image/cache/catalog/product/530x530.jpg

I can't work out how to stop that.